# When Tropical Plants Suffer a Big Frost

Tags: evolution, alternate-history, flora, post-apocalypse

Five million years ago, the warm Miocene descended into the chilly Pliocene before dropping to the frigid Pleistocene. This drop in temperature was so gradual that life soldiered on with no obvious signs of global catastrophe.

But in this alternate scenario, no such in-between existed, and five million years ago, the warm Miocene dropped straight down into the frigid Pleistocene. I've asked a question in a few different forums, and the answer ends up the same--yes, such a dramatic drop in global temperature is a potential for causing a mass extinction.

I imagine that life-forms restricted within the latitudinal boundaries of Cancer and Capricorn would be hit hardest, as this alternate Earth had been so warm for so many millions of years that jungles persisted within latitudes of 30 degrees.  This Pleistocene Big Freeze meant the extinction of 50-55% of all species on land, and the floral casualty list is as follows:

- Amborellales

[image]

- Zingiberales

[image]

- Myrtaceae

[image]

- Sapotaceae

[image]

- Adoxaceae

[image]

- Annonaceae

[image]

- Caricaceae

[image]

- Clusiaceae

[image]

- Chrysobalanaceae

[image]

- Meliaceae

[image]

- Passiofloraceae

[image]

- Myristicaceae

[image]

- Caryocaraceae

[image]

- Olacaceae

[image]

There are still a great deal of tropical plant species left, and being more seasonal, the subtropics weren't hit as hard as the tropics.  So with the listed plants extinct for five million years, would the subtropical plants colonize the empty niches?  Or would the tropical plants that did survive the initial cold snap just find more elbow room for greater distribution?

Comment: This seems like an open-ended, hypothetical question, the answer to which would depend on so many factors that you'd only get contingent opinions as answers. Running a model is probably the only way to answer it credibly. The list of plant extinct plant species and accompanying photos is unnecessary and buries your actual question at the end of a lot of exposition.

Comment: Did you know trees explode when they get too cold? It's the same effect as pipes bursting. That's basically what's going to happen to all your plant life.

Comment: I'd like to upvote this question, but there isn't really anything to answer and as phrased it's very broad. "Yes", pretty much sums it up.  The cold would cause a mass extinction. Survivors of that event would then colonize the equivalent niches either by temperate plants moving south or tropical plants that did survive adapting (or more likely a mixture of both those things). That's basically what always happens.

Comment: @Separatrix  No.  Just the pantropical ones.

Comment: Just a comment, John: While some of your recent questions have been a bit interesting, I do find it distracting to have the scroll through all the pictures. I don't mean to insult the botanists out there, but when I'm trying to read your questio, the images are a bit distracting.

Comment: @HDE226868  Would you have recognized the names if I DIDN'T bring up the images?

Comment: @JohnWDailey No, but I could have easily found the images using Google, if I really found it necessary, and more information about the planets elsewhere.